# How do i handle drop down menu using protractor test tool?

Tags: java, angularjs, protractor, automated-tests

I am new to this tool and I already know  how to handle drop down menu in a selenium webdriver can u suggest same how to handle it using protractor tool.?
Any leads,tech forums will be useful.

Below code I am navigating to web page and clicking on continue button, after clicking on it will navigate to next web page and in the dropdown menu selecting first option

```
describe("Adopt an animal on the zoo test site", function() {
    it("should be able to adopt an animal", function() {

        browser.get("http://www.thetestroom.com/jswebapp/")
        browser.switchTo().alert().accept;


            element(by.model("person.name")).sendKeys("subscribe to my channel");
            element(by.binding("person.name")).getText().then(function(text)
            {
                    console.log(text); 
            });
        element(by.buttonText("CONTINUE")).click();
        element(by.model("animal")).$('[value="1"]').click();
        element(by.partialButtonText("CONT")).click();
        });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use browser.actions().mouseMove() to work on dropdown selection as shown below:

```
**Code Snippet:**

 var dropdownElement=element(dropdown_locator);
 var dropdownOptionElement=element(dropdown_option_locator);

 dropdownElement.click().then(function () {
    browser.actions().mouseMove(dropdownOptionElement).click().perform();
  });
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: could u please provide me a demo?and can u explain How it is working.?
i have tried in a different fashion i am including the code in my question.

Comment: please check my code in my post. could u please guide me How your code can be used in my example.?